# actionscript project compiled as swf. how can i load it with flex and use the functions it provides?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, swfloader

I have an ActionScript project with several classes that i compiled as an swf using Adobe Flex (by creating an actionscript project and clicking on export -> release build)

Is there a way to load that swf so i'll be able to load it's classes and use them on a different swf ?

i know i can use the following code to load an swf file:
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

loader.load(new URLRequest("game.swf"));
addChild(loader);
```

(from [Loading a SWF into an ActionScript 3 project (Flex Builder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007803/loading-a-swf-into-an-actionscript-3-project-flex-builder)) but how can i actually create an instance of the classes i have in that swf ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function getDefinition for example to get a reference to the class to istanciate.

It will depend how your swf is loaded in what context.

```
//check if the class exist into applicationDomain
if (applicationDomain.hasDefinition(name)) {
  // get the class reference from applicationDomain
  var clazz:Class=Class(applicationDomain.getDefinition(name));
 // and instanciate
 var myInstance:XXX=(new clazz()) as XXX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [URL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html) from the Adobe LiveDocs site (Look at the section titled 'Embedding SWF files').